# See application logs lambda launch with SAM cli terraform hook

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-logging, aws-sam-cli

I have some tests that trigger a python AWS lambda locally using `sam local start-lambda --hook-name terraform`

The code of my python lambda emits some logs using the python `logging` lib. I would like to see those logs in console but I only see system logs (`START RequestId [...]`, `END RequestId [...]`, `REPORT RequestId [...]`) and `print(...)` invocations. No hint of `logging` messages.

I have tried using `sam logs ...` command but it needs the SAM stack name and, as I am using terraform hook for SAM, the template is an autogenerated json file that doesn't contain the stack name: no stack tag or description field so I have no clue on what to provide as stack name.

Also, I have listed cloudformation stacks in my AWS account finding none.

Any hint how can I manage to see `logging` logs in console?

Comment: In fact, I also see logging error logs, so I think it is some log level misconfiguration... In the lambda configuration I have set INFO as minimal log level...